# Is there a class for Arduino in C++ that is similar to the Minim class in Processing?

Tags: java, c++, arduino

I want to be able to take in a file for music, analyze it and then make lights light up to the music.  The only problem is, with the board that I built, using Processing has a big delay on the code that runs and it has maybe a obvious 10 ms gap.  I need a way to either bring the program back into Arduino, or somehow lower the response time.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged both c++ and java?

Comment: @Matthew Bocharnikov share your approach. Perhaps the delay will become more obvious and it will be easier to jump straight to the core of the issue. (off topic, I don't think I can perceive 10ms delays :D (as sound or image on a screen) so might be a chance to use perceptual limits to do less computing ;)).

Comment: @EJoshuaS By default Processing is mostly a collection of java libraries with a minimal IDE. Arduino is mostly a collection of c++ libraries for micro controller development. Both are useful for artists/designers/tinkerers to get into coding easier. Perhaps getting Arduino/Processing communication in the context of this question involves java/c++ behind the scenes. Personally processing/arduino would've worked better as tags, but my hunch is Matthew is new to using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you're dealing with the serial communication and where the bottlenecks would start to show up (audio processing/serial comms/both/something else/etc).

Regardless, if you want to do sound analysis on Arduino alone, that will be a challenge, as you'll have a lot less resources to do the FFT number crunching on an 8-bit micro controller.

I would go either of two ways:

1. Do the sound analysis as efficient as possible on the computer and map it to lights so the software(Processing) only sends minimal data to the firmware(Arduino)(just light data, on a need to know basis). If you have a ridiculous amount of lights you might want to use a serial converter than can handle higher baud rates, but in most cases you shouldn't need that.
2. Do a minimal sounds analysis on Arduino. If you got your light animations right, you can make something sound reactive using just the amplitude and a bit of easing without getting into FFT/MFC or anything fancier. If you really really want light responsiveness to frequencies consider using a 7 band frequency analyser chip like [MSGEQ7](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/MSGEQ7.pdf). There are Arduino breakouts that make that easier.